# PHP: Simultaneously Query Multiple Databases To Improve Load Time

Tags: php, jquery, html, oracle, oracle-call-interface

All,  I have a web page that loads data from 4-6 tables in 4 Oracle databases for approximately 10 schemas each on demand.  What I have setup is a require at the top of the page such as:

```
<?php
require_once('src/connects_client1.php');
require_once('src/connects_client2.php');
require_once('src/connects_client3.php');
require_once('src/connects_client4.php');
?>
```

Each of those files contains a connect string such as:

```
$connClient = oci_pconnect("Login", "Password", "//database:1521");
```

And a series of queries and executes such as:

```
$dailystatusClientSCHEMA = oci_parse($connClient, 'select * from OPS$SCHEMA.DAILY_STATUS order by table_name');

oci_execute($dailystatusClientSCHEMA);
```

This is then a part of a Jquery based tree view with a series of unordered lists and a PHP foreach loop that prints each row of data appropriately for the query results.

Some of the result sets contain upwards of a thousand rows of data.  This works, and displays the data in a usable format.

The problem is it takes 1 minute 52 seconds to load.  The end-user for this in the company thinks this is too long, and frankly I think it is too long also.  I am not a web developer, but it was most logical for this project to fall within our team so here I am.

Are there any ways that I can force all of the queries to load in a more simultaneous manner so that the data can be returned more quickly?  This is a VERY fast Exadata environment, so I don't believe there is any bottleneck at the DB and the web server has light load at any given time so I don't think there's a limit there, just in how I've built this page.

I really appreciate any solution to this one may provide.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps benchmark the different parts of the script from queries to whatever else is in the page to find where the bottleneck lies. It might either be the queries, pulling the result sets or even just waiting for the jquery data table to load the data. It might be faster to query the data, save it to session and paginate through that via ajax from the client side. Either way though, first thing is benchmark using microtime to find what is causing the bottleneck and focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

there's a bottle neck on `select *` try changing that to the fields you are actually interested in.

the RDBS has to work out what fields to return, what their names and datatypes are and how to allocate memory. By using named fields, the RDBS does not have to work out what fields are present in the tables you are querying.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, though through all of my research everything I found indicated not to use select * for the sake of possible changes in the table structure but that there was 0 performance difference in a query selecting specific columns vs. *

Comment: Update: Yes, load time remains largely unchanged, in fact based on my stopwatch it actually loaded slower.  That said, I appreciate your feedback and am glad that I have re-written the queries to not be select *